# "HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url" error message when trying to update conda in WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have an issue with installing packages from conda-forge and/or updating conda in WLS2/Ubuntu 22.04/Windows 11. When I try I get the following error message:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://repo.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https//repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64'
```

What I tried:

- disabling my firewall (symantec endpoint protection)
- restarting WSL and the whole computer
- changing permission with `chmod -R 777 ./anaconda3`
- turning off ssl verification with `conda config --set ssl_verify no`
- `sudo hwclock --hctosys` to fix system clock sync issues which prevented me from updating things in this WSL instance before

I would hate to have to resolve to manually installing an older version of conda, as it seems that every solution pointing to doing that uses 3+ years old versions. The solutions for the same error on windows, playing around with path/moving around dll's doesn't seem to apply to WSL, so what else can I do?